# Modifying a component's state from another component

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, seaside

I'm trying to set the instance variable of a child component from it's parent component inside a callback. Using the debugger I can see that the instance variable is set correctly in the callback, but on rendering the child component, the child component does not reflect the changes made.

So, is it illegal to modify a component's state from another component in seaside or am I doing something else wrong?

Example code:

```
MyParentComponent>> initialize
    super initialize.
    child := MyChildComponent new.

MyParentComponent>> renderContentOn: html 
  html render: child.   
  html anchor
     callback: [ 
        child property: 'Something'.
    ] ; with 'Navigate'.

MyParentComponent>> children 
  ^ Array with: child
```

Comment: It would help to post code exemplifying the issue.

Comment: I've added a portion of my code. The MyChildComponent has a instance variable 'property' and its value is used for rendering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little experimenting, I found the problem. In one of the rendering methods, I was creating a new component each time the page was rendered instead of reusing the one created in the `initialize` method.

That other component was used for navigation, where I set which main component was to be displayed based on the menu chosen.

So apparently, modifying state is not illegal in Seaside.

Comment: Modifying state is not "illegal" in callbacks. It is "illegal" in rendering methods. Apart from the bug you experienced, you will have problems with state backtracking. Seaside saves the state of your components before rendering them. When you do a "back", Seaside restores that state. In such a case, you will have lost those state changes. So never change state while rendering.

Answer (score 4):

You miss some `super initialize` in the parent component I guess.

I also suggest you don't work this way.

Do a `MyParentComponent>>child` with

```
  ^ child ifNil: [ child := MyChildComponent new ]
```

Also, don't do a `html render: child` but `html render: self child`.
That way you'll be able to swap components easily.

That way you are sure that child has been properly initialized.

Comment: oops, sorry I had set super initialize correctly. Made a mistake copy pasting.

Comment: Lazy initialization is not a good practice in Seaside. The reason is that you should not modify a component state while rendering. The components should be fully initialized (including child components). If you do it with lazy init, you will effectively change the state while rendering.

Comment: Isn't children meant to have them initialized properly if we use lazy init there? I find it a pain to not use self xxx. Just in case I need to change stuff while developing.

Comment: I call self children in my initialize method to ensure that they are initialized. Of course, in some cases, this is not the way to go for dynamic lists etc.